# Bugzilla: how do I configure one "urlbase" that works internally and externally?

Tags: bugzilla

PROBLEM:

I have Bugzillla 3.6 running on Linux, with a Windows 2008 server for our internal DNS.

I need to set Bugzilla's urlbase" so the SAME configuration will work for INTERNAL clients as well as EXTERNAL clients

EXAMPLE:

- urlbase=http://bugs.mycompany.com/bugzilla
- External access:

http://bugs.mycompany.com/bugzilla (xx.yy.zzz.nn)
<= Everything works OK

- Internal access (Windows DNS)

http://bugs/bugzilla (192.168.1.200)
<= Reaches initial page, then barfs trying to access remote address "bugs.mycompany.com" - because the host is actually inside our firewall

- WORKAROUND:

Hack c:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts on the client PC:

192.168.1.200  bugs.mycompany.com

Two problems with this workaround:

- I'd have to edit hosts for every client in the building
- It breaks for a laptop that might be external one minute, and an internal client the next

Any better ideas?????

Is there any "one size fits all" urlbase for Bugzilla????  Or does it *require* an FQDN?

Thank you VERY much in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Fix your firewall & NAT to allow hairpinning when internal clients try to connect to that port on the NAT's public IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to install Bugzilla twice, both configured to use the same database, but with different urlbase settings.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to set up an internal DNS server (not externally accessible) at your company (perhaps just by enabling DNS service on a server you've already got), have all your internal clients use that DNS server when they're on the internal network, and have that DNS server have an "A" record mapping bugs.mycompany.com to 192.168.1.200.

That way you don't have to hack the /etc/hosts file on all your clients (which is why DNS was created in the first place).

This has an advantage over my other suggestion, in that Bugzilla traffic from your internal clients would not have to traverse your network and your NAT gateway twice.